# ssh console в приложении на ruby on rails

Tags: веб-программирование, ruby-on-rails, ssh

Можно ли как то в rails приложении сделать: на WEB-странице, нажать на кнопку и увидеть консоль удаленного сервера по ssh? Если можно, то как?

Comment: Можно открыть shell на удаленной машине с правами web-сервера, но это не будет ssh.

Comment: Теоретически да, но трудоёмко. Надо вкрутить браузерный эмулятор терминала на страницу и наладить двухстороннюю связь (Вебсокет?) с демоном, который будет держать SSH-сессии. Вы уверены, что это стоит того?

Comment: Думаю, оно того не стоит. Спасибо за ответ! @D-side

Comment: @D-side, по-моему, ваш комментарий вполне тянет на ответ. ну, разве что последнее предложение можно опустить, а добавить про то, что к ruby-on-rails всё это будет иметь (как мне представляется) весьма малое отношение.